# Prove that: If $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x=0$ has positive roots, then $na_{n}x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+ a_{1}=0$ has positive roots.

Tags: derivatives

Prove that: If $a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x=0$ has positive roots, then $na_{n}x^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n-2}+...+ a_{1}=0$ has positive roots.
P/s: My grammar isn't good, so that my question is hard to understand.  I’m sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Your question is clear to understand, but without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: *please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.* These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is an easy application of Rolle's Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem.

Comment: Please add your thoughts about the question. The site discourages people asking question without even try to solve. No matter what attempts you made, type them into your post, and people would help you. Otherwise you would receive a lot of downvotes, and your post would highly likely be put on hold for further improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be a positive root of the given function ($=f(x)$,say).We know that 0 is also a root of f(x). Apply, Rolle's theorem between them(We can apply that as polynomials are both continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb R$)
$$\Longrightarrow \exists c\in(0,\alpha):f'(c) = 0$$
which is the required statement to be proven.

Hope it is helpful